# Como crear un indice con php y mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

En el siguiente fragmento de mi codigo hago una consulta a una base de datos Mysql y creo una pagina del pdf con Fpdf pero al momento de mostrar el index de mi archivo este aparece en blanco.Codigo:

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT titulo_editado,texto_editado as contenido from texto_editado where id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "i",$id);
$query->execute();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$titulo_editado, $contenido);
$query ->store_result();
if ($query ->num_rows > 0) {
    $mpdf->IndexEntry($titulo_editado);
    $mpdf ->WriteHTML('<p><span style="background-color:#7f8c8d">Algo</span></p>');
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
        $mpdf -> WriteHTML('<div>'.$contenido.'</div>');
    }
}
$query -> close();
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h2>Indice De Contenido</h2>',2);
$mpdf->InsertIndex();
$mpdf -> Output('Nombre.pdf', 'I');
```

Esto me muestra muy bien la variable `$contenido` en mi pdf pero la variable `$titulo_editado` no la muestra **cabe resaltar que la variable solo no la muestra fuera del metodo indexEntry() en cualquier otra parte del documento si lo hace**

Comment: Intenté con `$titulo = (string)$titulo_editado;` para pasar la variable a String y no funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESUELTO!! el metodo `INdexEntry()` ya no se usa actualmente, solo cambie mi codigo por el siguiente 
`$query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT titulo_editado,texto_editado as contenido from texto_editado where id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "i",$id);
$query->execute();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$titulo_editado, $contenido);
$query ->store_result();
if ($query ->num_rows > 0) {
    $mpdf->IndexEntry($titulo_editado); //esta linea se elimina
    $mpdf ->WriteHTML('<p><span style="background-color:#7f8c8d">Algo</span></p>');
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
        $mpdf -> WriteHTML('<indexentry content="'.$titulo_editado.'"/>.'<div>'.$contenido.'</div>'); //esta linea se modifica
    }
}
$query -> close();
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h2>Indice De Contenido</h2>',2);
$mpdf->InsertIndex();
$mpdf -> Output('Nombre.pdf', 'I');`